# Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in /wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 333

Tags: customization, rewrite-rules

I get this error while trying to load wordpress in a smarty template. But when I visit wordpress I dont get that error any where.

the code I use to load wordpress is :

```
{php}include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php';
get_header();{/php}
```

The Error :
Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in /wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
just add this code before including wp-blog-header.php.

```
global $wp_rewrite;
```

source: https://github.com/kayue/WordpressBundle/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

Read [Don’t include wp-load, please.](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) Then look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47059/73) to understand the difference to the load of `wp-blog-header.php`.

Comment: I changed wp-load.php to wp-blog-header.php and still getting the same error.