# Call to undefined function add_action()

Tags: ajax

I created a Theme Options page where the user can edit some of the theme settings. Now I'm trying to save this options asynchronously but it seems I have some problems integrating the handler file into WP.

The Theme Options is a simple admin page nested under Appearance.

When pressing the save button:

```
<a id = "save-settings" href = "#" data-nonce = "<?php wp_create_nonce("sace_settings_nonce") ?>"><?php echo _('Save Settings') ?></a>
```

the following JS script is called:

```
function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : themeRoot + 'framework/AsyncAction.php',
        data: { action  : 'save_settings',
                name    : 'John',}
        }).done(function(resp) {
            alert(resp);
        });
},
```

The handler `.php` file contains:

```
<?php
include_once('SettingsController.php');
define ('SAVE_SETTINGS', 'save_settings');

add_action('wp_ajax_save_settings', 'save_settings');

function save_settings(){
    global $controller;
    $name = esc_attr($_POST['name']);
    echo 'Hi, ' . $name;
}

?>
```

Running this code throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()
```

I also tryied:

1. hook the action on init -> same problem
2. remove the hook completely. This caused the undefined error to be thrown for `esc_attr()`

It seems that I don't have access to any of the WP functions but I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: See this question/answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47059/11761

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wordpress has a native AJAX file that should do all that you want, and this will ensure that all native WP functions are included. If you require additional functionality from **'framework/AsyncAction.php'**, you can `include_once()`, as you do with **'SettingsController.php'**.

See the Codex for more information and examples - [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

If you wish to use AJAX on the front end of your website, you need to add the following lines to your **functions.php** file -

```
/** Declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) */
wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax-request', admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```