# What's the most minimal way in which a page can be hooked into WP?

Tags: pages, page-template, api, customization, mvc

I do a fair bit with custom API's on WordPress-based sites, typically by creating page templates.

However, creating a custom page template, then creating a WP Page that utilizes it is kind of a pain (not to mention the ugly names I have to use to keep users from deleting or changing them)*.

I prefer the low overhead of plain php files, but then I obviously lose access to WP functions.

Is there a better, more MVC-esque way to get custom logic that can call WP functions firing at specific URLs and yet keep it hidden from the admin?

*I know I can manually un-register pages from the admin, but this is even more of a pain!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to use wordpress functions outside wordpress files?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files)

Comment: I make a lot of one off OO plugins for clients as a way to essentially abstract out custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

The `template_redirect` hook *might* be what you are looking for.

```
function template_redir_wpse_97289($content) {
  // code or file include, for example
}
add_filter('template_redirect','template_redir_wpse_97289',1);
```

That will fire just before the page template is loaded so you could use it to load your own templates.