# Use a template file for a specific url without creating a page

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, page-template

I wonder if its possible to use a template file for a specific url without having to create a page for that template.

This is my simplified problem:

I have created a page in WP with some link content that points to a specific url with some trailing form data: *(mysite.com/retail/?a=test&b=1234)*.

I want that url (retail) to automatically use my template file template-retail.php that I have in the child theme directory, without having to create a page named ”retail” & select the template page from there. There is only external content in the template-retail.php file, nothing from Wordpress itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: You would need to create an HTAccess redirect to the file, then process the request there.

Comment: I dont have access to the .htaccess file in this case. Is there any other way?

Comment: there are plugins that may give you access to do these type of things, either way you'll need to upload a custom file to the server so it has something to hit.

Comment: Not sure about all of the details of your project but the first things that come to mind are [`template_redirect`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97301/21376) or an [endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can just look at url, load the file and exit.

That can be done when WordPress loaded its environment, e.g. on `'init'`.

```
add_action('init', function() {
  $url_path = trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
  if ( $url_path === 'retail' ) {
     // load the file if exists
     $load = locate_template('template-retail.php', true);
     if ($load) {
        exit(); // just exit if template was found and loaded
     }
  }
});
```

Note that doing so a *real* page with slug "retail" can never be used.

This is pretty easy, but also hardcoded, so if you need this for a single page it's fine. If you need to control more urls, have a look to the solution proposed in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162476/35541).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can not get the above code to work. This is never true:
"if ( $url_path === 'retail' ) {"
The $url_path is a string with the value:
"http://example.com/retail"

Comment: Try to `var_dump($url_path);` and see how it looks like and adjust the code. That value depends on your *real* url. E.g. for custom home url, or WP installed in subfolder may be different. @Keat

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry for the late answer. 
I used this solution and it works perfect.
`$url_path = trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');`
`$templatename = 'retail';`
`$pos = strpos($url_path, $templatename);`
`if ($pos !== false) {`

Comment: Hi, I have just tried this and it loaded my template fine but I notice that a few other bits in the page are not working ie I have a `echo do_shortcode()` in the header but it's not working and the actual shortcode is being displayed - is this something to do with Wordpress not initialising these once the template has loaded due to the `exit()`?

Comment: Further to previous comment, have changed the hook from `init` to `wp_loaded` and shortcodes are now loading.

Answer (score 10):

The `init` action isn't appropriate for what you're trying to achieve. You should be using the `template_include` filter instead. You'd combine this with `get_query_var` to retrieve the URL params to check what template needs to be loaded. Here are the links:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Code:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'portfolio' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'portfolio-page-template.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The WordPress-way to do this is with `page-templates`. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

You only need a code for the WordPress template. In your WordPress theme you can create a page template and rename it to

`page-id.php`

That particular page will automatically pick it up and use the template.

For example if your page has an id of 5874 you'll name the template as `page-5784.php`

You can also name the template based on the page slug. For example if the page slug is `hello-world` then the template name will be `page-hello-world.php`

Also see: 
 - https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Answer (score 0):

@shivanand-sharma this is perfect and cleaner method (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) to create any page like any other in wordpress, and if you want to hide your page, i just use the simple and efective plugin 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/exclude-pages/'

I must say that i was in need of a URL to make **POST** or **GET** to my own page and save some session data 'WC()->session', and this solves this and other problems, because **you can have a backbone of custom php code including all the 'require('wp-load') etc' of the entire wordpress, woocommerce etc** to work with through, **mysite.com/index.php/MYPAGE** .....

You just need to :

**First:** Create a file inside your theme location as a template of the new page something like 'wp-content/themes/mytheme/customtemplate.php' (Comment is important so the 'Template Name' can be observed by Wordpress) :

```
<?php /* Template Name: WhateverName */ 
echo 'Hello World';echo '</br>';
var_dump(WC()->session); 
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

**Second:** Create a page at wordpress normally through 'wp-admin' > Pages (Let's say a name like **MYPAGE**, or you can change the slug whatever you want) and off course link the previous template as the template of this page which is name **'WhateverName'** on the template attributtes section.

So, Let's open the new page **'mysite.com/index.php/MYPAGE'** and you will see.

```
Hello World
object(WC_Session_Handler)#880 .....................
```

**Extras:** Let's create javascript or jquery functions in cart, checkout, whatever you can imagine inside 'script' HTML tags, and include code like this:

```
var data = { action : actionName, dataA : etcA, dataB : etcB}
$.ajax({
    type:     'post',
    url:      'index.php/MYPAGE',
    data:     data,
    success:  function( response ) {
    },
    complete: function() {
    }
});
```