# Redirecting old post url to 404 in wordpress using htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess

In WordPress I have a post with URL `https://www.example.com/article.html`.

I renamed its permalink to `https://www.example.com/article-new.html`.

Now if I open the old URL `https://www.example.com/article.html` then it auto 301 redirects to `https://www.example.com/article-new.html` 
due to the WordPress built-in feature by default.

However, I want to show a 404 when someone tries to open `https://www.example.com/article.html`.

I tried putting this in `.htaccess` but it gives a 500 server error instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 404 /article.html
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing this *within* WordPress is probably the preferred approach, as mentioned in @Harrison's answer, however, to answer your specific queries...

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> Redirect 404 /article.html
> ```

*Aside:* The `RewriteEngine` directive relates to mod_rewrite, however, `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive - so these two directives are unrelated.

However, this should "work" with a default WordPress front-controller, so maybe you have a conflict with other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Try the following instead, using mod_rewrite at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file (before any existing WordPress directives):

```
RewriteRule ^article\.html$ - [R=404]
```

If this still results in an error, then try resetting the 404 error document (to the Apache default) before this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

You'll need to clear your browser cache to clear the cached (permanent) 301 redirect to the new URL.

Comment: Thanks...first I tried RewriteRule ^article\.html$ - [R=404] but it din't worked so I tried ErrorDocument 404 default
RewriteRule ^article\.html$ - [R=404] and it worked..but the 404 page is not the default wordpress page..its just white page with 404 error. is there a way to display 404 wordpress page?

Comment: The initial 500 error you were getting suggests there was a "problem" with the previously defined Apache 404 custom `ErrorDocument`. What (if anything) was this set to previously? However, you wouldn't necessarily expect to be able to trigger the WordPress 404 page from `.htaccess` directly (which is essentially outside of WordPress itself). Does your theme have a `404.php` file? This might need modifying to make it work in this way?  (Which is why it might be preferable to solve this entirely within WordPress instead?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the right way to change htaccess, but you could try manually redirecting the old url to your 404 template. Adapted from this post:

[Use a template file for a specific url without creating a page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182708/use-a-template-file-for-a-specific-url-without-creating-a-page)

Using your example URL slug:

```
function wpse_manual_redirect( ){
    $str = 'article.html';
    $url = parse_url( add_query_arg( array() ), PHP_URL_PATH );
    $url_length = strlen($url);
    $last_segment = substr( $url , $url_length - strlen( $str ) );

    if ( $last_segment === $str ){
        $load = locate_template( '404.php', true );
        if ( $load ){
            exit();
        }

    }


}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_manual_redirect' );
```

Include in functions.php.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks. I tried it.
URL redirects to "page not found" but when I check redirect status for that old url via http://www.redirect-checker.org it shows 200 OK.
I want the status to be 404.

Please advice.