# How to display admin bar when using WP_USE_THEMES = false?

Tags: theme-development, admin-bar

So I'm using WordPress in a 'themeless' manner, i.e. not using a "blog" template. My site files are in the root directory (not in the theme folder), and WordPressis installed in its own `/wordpress/` directory. The only thing my theme exists for is customization of the back-end, including re-branding and custom post types. (I'm basically avoiding plug-ins and widgets and doing a bespoke implementation of WordPress)

With this set-up, is there a way I can get the admin bar to display when my clients view the front-end pages like it normally does?

NOTE: I've tried adding `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` to no avail. I think this might have something to do with my custom file structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'wordpress/wp-load.php';
wp_footer();
```

Maybe you have to remove some things from the footer-file (e.g. Powered By WordPress). With `var_dump( $wp_actions );` you can see which actions was executed (a list of action hooks). And with `var_dump( $wp_filter['wp_footer'] );` you can see which actions are registred for the specific hook (here `wp_footer`).

Comment: Hey thanx for the answer! The thing is though I've done this and I still get no admin bar. I've added `wp_footer` at many different points of my script and I get absolutely no render at all. Mind you, I'm in the top-level directory and not in the THEME directory.

Comment: I tested it in the opposit way. WordPress in the root, the file with adminbar in a subfolder. This works great. I think it is a path problem. Wp setup ABSPATH to `yourdomain.tld/wordpress/` and it seems, that everything below this path (`yourdomain.tld/`) does not exists for WP. I try something different, maybe it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If WordPress is being loaded from an external PHP file by including `wp-blog-header.php` and the `WP_USE_THEMES` constant is set to `false`, the `template_redirect` hook will not be fired. This is important because `template_redirect` is how the Toolbar is initialized on the front end. Taking a look at `default-filters.php` we can see where the Toolbar is initialized:

```
...
// Admin Bar
// Don't remove. Wrong way to disable.
add_action( 'template_redirect', '_wp_admin_bar_init', 0 ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'admin_init', '_wp_admin_bar_init' ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'before_signup_header', '_wp_admin_bar_init' ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'activate_header', '_wp_admin_bar_init' ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
add_action( 'in_admin_header', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 0 );
...
```

A function can be added via plugin or theme to trigger the initialization of the Toolbar:

```
function wpse240134_wp_admin_bar_init() {
    _wp_admin_bar_init();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse240134_wp_admin_bar_init' );
```

*Note that `_wp_admin_bar_init()` is considered an internal function for WordPress so use it at your own risk.*

See also [Admin Bar (Toolbar) not showing on custom PHP file that loads WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240134/admin-bar-not-showing-on-own-php/240152#240152).

More details on loading WP using an external PHP file: [What is the correct way to use wordpress functions outside wordpress files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files)