# Admin Bar (Toolbar) not showing on custom PHP file that loads WordPress

Tags: php, customization, wp-admin, admin, admin-bar

I've made **my own PHP page** and used it as a part of my WordPress website. I'm using some WordPress  functions and want to have it fully integrated with WordPress itself.

Although I've loaded WordPress, the Admin Bar is not loading at the top of the page. **It actually doesn't even show in HTML structure** (I tried to search <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for *wpadminbar*, no results.)

---

What I've done -

#### 1. Included WP file

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

#### 2. Added wp_head();

Right before `</head>`

#### 2. Added get_header();

Right after `<body>`

#### 3. Added wp_footer();

Right before `</body>`

---

Also tried:

#### show_admin_bar(true);

#### get_footer();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If WordPress is loaded from outside of the main WordPress files using a separate PHP script that includes `wp-load.php` then the `/template-loader.php` file will not be loaded and therefore the `template_redirect` action will not be triggered.

This is important because `template_redirect` is how the Toolbar is initialized on the front end. Taking a look at `default-filters.php` we can see where the Toolbar is initialized:

```
...
// Admin Bar
// Don't remove. Wrong way to disable.
add_action( 'template_redirect', '_wp_admin_bar_init', 0 ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'admin_init', '_wp_admin_bar_init' ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'before_signup_header', '_wp_admin_bar_init' ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'activate_header', '_wp_admin_bar_init' ); // <-- initialize Toolbar
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
add_action( 'in_admin_header', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 0 );
...
```

A function can be added via plugin or theme to trigger the initialization of the Toolbar:

```
function wpse240134_wp_admin_bar_init() {
    _wp_admin_bar_init();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse240134_wp_admin_bar_init' );
```

*Note that `_wp_admin_bar_init()` is considered an internal function for WordPress so use it at your own risk.*

It's also worth noting that if WordPress is being loaded from an external PHP file by including `wp-blog-header.php` and the `WP_USE_THEMES` constant is set to `false`, the `template_redirect` hook will again not be fired, so the `wpse240134_wp_admin_bar_init()` function above can be used to get the admin bar to show up when `WP_USE_THEMES` is set to `false`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Demonstration  of loading WordPress from an external PHP file.
 * 
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files
//require ('./wp-load.php');

require ('./wp-blog-header.php');

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body id="body" <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="page" class="site">
        <header id="header" class="site-header"></header>

        <div id="content" class="site-content">
            <h1>Test of loading WordPress from external PHP file</h1>
        </div>

        <footer id="footer" class="site-footer"></footer>
    </div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

More details on loading WP using an external PHP file: [What is the correct way to use wordpress functions outside wordpress files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files)

Answer (score 0):

I really like Dave Romseys answer, but I think it can be a bit leaner if you solely want the admin bar (as per original question).

Inside wp-blog-header.php you will find the following:

```
            do_action( 'template_redirect' );
```

If you add that to your custom php applications header you will get the admin bar. I was getting a 404 template when using Dave's method, so this may work better for you.