# how to invoke wordpress API from other existing PHP system

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, multisite

We have our own php system, now we want to have a blog function. Because wordpress are widely used, so we decided to use it. And now I want to invoke wordpress's function , for example `wp_insert_user` , how can I can do that ?

Suppose my system is `A` and installed on `/var/www/A`, and wordpress is `WP` and installed on `/var/www/WP`. I can put them together like this `/var/www/A/WP`, but I don't think that's a good idea.

If we use `/var/www/A` and `/var/www/WP`, how can I invoke wordpress's function from a php file that in project `A`?  Using curl?

Edit:=======================================================

Now I put WP below A (/var/www/A/wordpress)

Here, in my project A , I have a logon.php, what I want to do is invoke 'wp_insert_user' function to create a new wordpress user when user logon our system (just a test purpose).

I put the following code at the beginning of my logon.php

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/var/www/A/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Before I add the two line, when I visit my site, the url is :

```
http://localhost/myproject/www/logon.php
```

After I add it, the url become this:

```
http://localhost/myproject/www/logon.php/wp-admin/install.php
```

what worse, all the style of my logon.php are completely gone.

My requirement is simple:

```
when user logon our system, invoke wordpress function 'wp_insert_user' 
to create a user for wordpress. Just to create a new user, no more action.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following snippet at the start of your PHP file to load WordPress in it.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require('wp-blog-header.php'); // chage the path to match your WP directory
//the rest of your code here
```

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, you could use `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require('wp-load.php'); // chage the path to match your WP directory
//the rest of your code here
```

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47059/17305) explains that:

> It loads all of WordPress, but doesn't call wp() or invoke the
>   template loader (used by themes). Method 2 will be a little
>   lighter-weight, but should give you the same functionality.

Comment: I update my question, pls help me.

Comment: Looks like you didn't install WordPress... Install it first.

Comment: Oh, maybe, I install it before, so I just copy the installed file to /var/www/A. I reinstall it. Thanks

Comment: After I install it, still got the problem.

Comment: try to access it directly to confirm

Answer (score 2):

Like RRikesh said, including `wp-blog-header.php` will work but it also has lines of code that includes theme templates. You can take it one step further and just include `wp-load.php` so you have the bare bones, no extra frills or extra stuff to load.

Comment: The theme templates won't load if you're using `define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );`. This [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47059/17305) talks about the difference. Effectively, including `wp-load` should be lighter.