# Use wordpress functions in another PHP file

Tags: plugins, loop, wp-load.php

I have created in my theme folder a PHP file named gallery.php. In this file I want to use WP_Query function, but I can't do this because it shows error.

Is possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to use wordpress functions outside wordpress files?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put your `gallery.php` in the same theme folder, where the theme's `functions.php` resides. Then add a single line in `functions.php`:

```
get_template_part('gallery','');
```

It'll include the `gallery.php` file into `functions.php` and `gallery.php` will behave like `functions.php`.

So, you have to keep in mind that, `functions.php` file is a file for WordPress and PHP functions. So anything out-of-format without proper formatting may occur error into the whole site - and `functions.php` is a core file of any theme.

I don't think it's impossible using `WP_Query()` inside a `functions.php` - but you have to format and place it properly.