# I am trying to call external database recieving error

Tags: php, jquery

My case is different from the case defined here .. I am calling an external databse in my functional.php file by this method

```
function newdata()
    {
    $newdb = new wpdb("onlinedu_newuser","oeb_new%12", "onlinedu_schooldata", "localhost");
    $newdb->show_errors();
    }
```

Now the problem is In this database there are college and universities name, which I want to use in a form to calculate the competition, the calculator is made in java and jquerry.

When I load this function

```
newdata();
```

At the top of my calculator.php which have a scrtip of calculation and college name fields.
Every thing seems fine the college name appears but when I click calculate it is returning an error

```
Class 'Wpdb' Not Found In /Home/Onlinedu/Public_html/Wp-Content/Themes/Edu_2013/Db.Php On Line 9
```

Please Guide me How I can call this database in jquery ?

No I am using it in function.php file the data base is in the same server.. shall I also provide jquerry as it has nothing to do with jquerry I just need a method How can I connect and use the tables in my jquerry ? as in wamp I use connectmysql command at the beggining of jquerry seems fine but not working on live server.

Comment: Is this happening within WordPress or outside of it? Do you really mean, what you wrote in the last sentence (I see no jQuery anywhere in the question)?

Comment: Are you trying to use the WordPress function (well, class) `wpdb` outside of WordPress?  If so, see here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files

Comment: No I am using it in function.php file the data base is in the same server.. shall I also provide jquerry as it has nothing to do with jquerry I just need a method How can I connect and use the tables in my jquerry ? as in wamp I use connectmysql command at the beggining of jquerry seems fine but not working on live server.