# Creating wordpress user registration form

Tags: php, functions, forms

I am having a form page called Test Form with this form :

```
<div id="container">
<form action="wp-content/themes/max-magazine/TestForm.php" method="post" name="myForm">
User <input type="text"  name="uname" />
Email  <input id="email" type="text" name="uemail" />
Password  <input type="password"  name="upass" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
</div>
```

And in backend am having a php file named TestForm.php

```
<?php 
function create_account(){
$user = 'AccountID';
$pass = 'AccountPassword';
$email = 'email@domain.com';
if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role( 'contributor' );
} 
}
add_action('init','create_account');
?>
```

Now if this function is defined in function.php then it works fine and create the user but same function in TestForm.php does not work. Please help

Also I will be fetching data from form like this :

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['upass'];
$email = $_POST['uemail'];
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are sending the data from the form directly to `TestForm.php` file, which is a PHP script outside of WordPress logic. It is and independent script. You could set the form's `action` attribute to a empty string, this way the form data is sent to same page that contains the form, which is part of WordPress:

```
<div id="container">
    <form method="post" name="myForm">
        User <input type="text"  name="uname" />
        Email  <input id="email" type="text" name="uemail" />
        Password  <input type="password"  name="upass" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

In this case, the form data is sent to a Wordpress page and the `add_action('init','create_account');` is triggered if you add it to `functions.php` file, for example like this:

```
add_action('init','create_account');
function create_account(){
    //You may need some data validation here
    $user = ( isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : '' );
    $pass = ( isset($_POST['upass']) ? $_POST['upass'] : '' );
    $email = ( isset($_POST['uemail']) ? $_POST['uemail'] : '' );

    if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
       $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
       if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
           //user has been created
           $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
           $user->set_role( 'contributor' );
           //Redirect
           wp_redirect( 'URL_where_you_want_redirect' );
           exit;
       } else {
           //$user_id is a WP_Error object. Manage the error
       }
    }

}
```

P.D.: I suggest you to use a modern HTML5 form markup and input types

Comment: So i cant make TestForm.php page ?

Comment: Then problem is how to get values of user,email and password in functions.php from the form myForm?

Comment: You have access to `$_POST` inside the `create_account()` function, so you get the values as you do in any other form in PHP. And you can make `TestForm.php` but [you will have to load Wordpress engine in that file](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files), which I really think you don't want.

Comment: And where am i defining this function?Is it in functions.php?Or in TestForm.php?

Comment: In `functions.php`

Comment: So you mean i should do it in functions.php?Then how the form will know that it need to response to which php file?And what if i need to redirect it to some other page on successfull registration

Comment: Then how to redirect to other page on success?

Comment: Use [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect). I think you are confusing URL with PHP script location.

Comment: Please can you tell where to put that wp_direct ?

Comment: Put `wp_redirect` where you want it to be executed, obviously. For example, if you want it to be executed after a successful `wp_create_user`, put it after checking if `wp_create_user` has created a user correctly. See edited answer. I think your answer about "Creating wordpress user registration form" is alrady answered, more localized questions should be asked in new questions, for exmaple, `how to use wp_redirect`? If not we can have a endless discussion here.

Comment: I would suggest adding some `isset()` checks to the `$_POST` data. Otherwise you might see PHP warnings.