# How to use Wordpress methods (themes, plugins, context) with Behat?

Tags: testing, composer

My Wordpress project is running with a composer inside my plugin folder, just to test Behat a little bit, i'm not using Bedrock Wordpress yet.

I can run Behat to do some behavior tests using the browser, but sometimes i need to use a method from Wordpress, but i can't access it.

Anyone know how can i use my Wordpress context (my plugins methods, my themes methods, wordpress native methods) inside Behat Test Class?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is something like »[What is the correct way to use wordpress functions outside wordpress files?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47049/22534)« what you mean?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I will test it inside of my Behat context and i'll post here the results.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://github.com/wdalmut/WordPressExtension . It hooks like he is using some WordPress functions, but I'm not sure how he is loading them.

Comment: I guess this extension just adds a new Wordpress in your folder, and then autoloads all the functions. But i need the context of MY wordpress, not a new one. I need to use my plugin functions, my theme functions..