# How to add shortcode to HTML file (not showing on website)

Tags: shortcode, html

Im trying to add a plugin shortcode into an HTML document so that when you clickthe "Music" icon on the site a popup appears with the plugin widget in it.

This is the shortcode in the HTML file (using the plugin "Custom CSS & JS), ive wrapped it in a div, it works with an iframe but I cant get a shortcode to appear.

```
   [lbg_audio3_html5 settings_id='1']
```

This is the page - https://ellislanding.garywestjr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcodes work because WordPress is set up to parse them when it outputs content. Including a shortcode in any plain HTML file won't work because there's nothing but the web browser to parse the code.

It's possible to include some WP methods - such as in this question [What is the correct way to use WordPress functions outside WordPress files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files) - but you'd likely be better off just taking the full HTML the shortcode outputs and pasting that into your file, rather than trying to bootstrap WP into HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this, how would I get the HTML from the shortcode that a plugin creates?

Comment: Add the shortcode in a WordPress post or page. Then view the page on the front end and use the Inspector to see the HTML.

Comment: (You may need to check and see if any other files are output with the HTML - like JS or CSS that would affect how it works or how it looks.)

Comment: ive solved this now thanks guys!

Comment: If this answer helped please select it - and if you solved it some other way please write your own answer so others searching for something similar know what worked for you. :)