# How to return a record from a custom table by sending an AJAX request

Tags: ajax

I am trying to return a record from a custom table.
On the client side, I am sending an AJAX request.

```
<script>
    
    var eventId;
    var xmlhttp;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    
    function doclick(ddl){
        $evtid=-1;      
        $evtid =ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
              document.getElementById('hideme').value = 
              ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
              document.getElementById('ename').value = 
              ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
              xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.memoriesof.website/id.php", true);
              xmlhttp.send();            
        }
          
    function callback(){
    
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
</script>
```

$evtid is getting the correct data.

The id.php file:

```
<?php
$wpdb;
$sql='';
$eid;
$result;
echo print_r($result);
echo 'Howdy: '. print_r($eid);
try {
$sql='select description from mo_events where id = '. '11';
$result = $wpdb.get_results($sql);
    
    echo "Im'''trying...";    
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    echo 'Caught me.';
} finally {    
    echo "finally...out: ". print_r($result);
}
echo 'all the way... : '.print_r($result);
```

This is what shows on the Description textarea:
"1Howdy: 1finally...out: 1}

So it looks like I have the client side working.
Can someone help me figure out how to get the data back to the client?
Thanks...Dan';

Answer (score 0):

- Your code (both client-side and server-side) makes no sense and is very ugly.
- You're not [loading WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files) in your custom PHP script, so there's no way `$wpdb` would work.
- To call a method of an object, you should do `$wpdb->get_results('... sql ...')`.

You shouldn't call PHP scripts directly anyway. It's better to create a [REST endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) or a [rewrite endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/) inside your theme or plugin.